# How would I pull the key from firebase of an already created cell that someone tapped on

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How would I pull the key from firebase of an already created cell (I'm using TableView) that someone tapped on, and create that as a local var? I want to know this so I can transfer the key into the next view so I can make a generic storyboard but the text fields change with the key. This also means I want to set the data in one view controller then send it to another which if I'm using the same database (I am) for this I would need it to be edited on the second view controller.

I've already got this much on the second view controller (for firebase)

```
  refObjective = Database.database().reference().child("objective");
       

        let bodyFire = refObjective.childByAutoId().child("body")
      bodyFire.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let bodyOnFire  = snapshot.value as? String
            self.text?.text = bodyOnFire

        })
```

and the entire view first/tableview controller

```
//  WeeklyObjectivesEditorViewController.swift
//  Studioso
//
//  Created by Charles Porth on 8/29/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Studioso. All rights reserved.
//


import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseDatabase

class WeeklyObjectivesEditorViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
   

    @IBOutlet weak var View2: UITabBarItem!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar1: UITextField!

    //defining firebase reference var
    var refToolbars: DatabaseReference!
    
    var refToolbars2: DatabaseReference!
    let arrayOfIDs: NSMutableArray = [""]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewToolbar: UITableView!
   
    //list to store all the artist
    var toolbarList = [ToolbarModel]()
    
   
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return toolbarList.count
      
    }
    
   
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        //creating a cell using the custom class
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
        
        //the artist object
        let toolbar: ToolbarModel
        
        //getting the artist of selected position
        toolbar = toolbarList[indexPath.row]
    
        //adding values to labels
        
        cell.label.text = toolbar.toolbar1
        
        //returning cell
        return cell
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var Remove: UIBarButtonItem!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var add: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBAction func buttonToolbar(_ sender: UIButton) {
        addToolbar()
        restructureDBKeys()
        //reloading the tableview
        self.tableViewToolbar.reloadData()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Add this
        tableViewToolbar.delegate = self
        tableViewToolbar.dataSource = self

        //getting a reference to the node artists
        refToolbars = Database.database().reference().child("toolbars");
        
       print(selectedKey + "this is the selected key")
        dataPassedMedium = selectedKey
        
        let bodyFire = refToolbars.childByAutoId().child("body")
        
             //this is how you get it
        refToolbars.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.value is NSNull{
                //Handle errors
            }
            else{
                self.arrayOfIDs.removeAllObjects()
                if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
                    //dict.allKeys is all the IDs
                    for ID in dict.allKeys{
                        self.arrayOfIDs.add(ID as! String) //Will always be a string in Firebase
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        
 
        //observing the data changes
        refToolbars.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            //if the reference have some values
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                
                //clearing the list
                self.toolbarList.removeAll()
                
                //iterating through all the values
                for toolbar in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    //getting values
                    let toolbarObject = toolbar.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let toolbarId  = toolbarObject?["id"]
                    let toolbarToolbar1 = toolbarObject?["toolbar1"]
                    let toolbarBody  = toolbarObject?["body"]
                    let toolbarTitle = toolbarObject?["title"]

//                    creating artist object with model and fetched values
                  
                    //creating artist object with model and fetched values
                    let toolbar = ToolbarModel(id: toolbarId as! String?, toolbar1: toolbarToolbar1 as! String?, title: toolbarTitle as! String?, body: toolbarBody as! String?)
                    
                    
                    //appending it to list
                    self.toolbarList.append(toolbar)
                } 
                
                //reloading the tableview
                self.tableViewToolbar.reloadData()
            }
        })       
        
      
    }
    
    func addToolbar(){
        //generating a new key inside artists node
        //and also getting the generated key
        let key = refToolbars.childByAutoId().key
        
        //creating artist with the given values
        let toolbar = ["id":key,
                       "toolbar1": toolbar1.text! as String,

        ]
        
        //adding the artist inside the generated unique key
        refToolbars.child(key).setValue(toolbar)
        
        
   
        
    }

    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    

    
    
   
    
   
{

    var valueToPass:String! // #1 i added this one first
    var selectedKey: String!
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Get Cell Label
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
        
      //  valueToPass = currentCell.label.text
        
        //the artist object     
        //getting the artist of selected position
       // toolbar = toolbarList[indexPath.row]
        let destinationVC = AddNewObjectiveViewController()
        destinationVC.transferRow = selectedKey
        
        selectedKey = (arrayOfIDs[indexPath.row] as? String)!
         print(selectedKey + "this is the selected key@ selected")
         print(dataPassedMedium + "this is the dataPassedMedium key@ selected")
        
        dataPassedMedium = selectedKey
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "weeklyadd", sender: self)
   
    
    }
    func restructureDBKeys() {
        
        
        // let arrayOfIDs: NSMutableArray = [""]
        //this is how you get it
        refToolbars.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.value is NSNull{
                //Handle errors
            }
            else{
                self.arrayOfIDs.removeAllObjects()
                if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
                    //dict.allKeys is all the IDs
                    for ID in dict.allKeys{
                        self.arrayOfIDs.add(ID as! String) //Will always be a string in Firebase
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        
    }
    
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // #2 used if let as? UINavigationController

        let destinationVC = navigationController?.topViewController as? AddNewObjectiveViewController
        //  destinationVC?.transferRow = valueToPass
        destinationVC?.transferRow = selectedKey
        
        print("data should be transfered" )
         dataPassedMedium = selectedKey

        if let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
            let destinationVC = navigationController.topViewController as? AddNewObjectiveViewController
               destinationVC?.transferRow = selectedKey
    print("data should be transfered" )
        }
        
    }



    

    

}
var dataPassedMedium: String!
```

and the entire view second controller

```
//
//  AddNewObjective.swift
//  Studioso
//
//  Created by Charles Porth on 9/21/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Studioso. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import QuartzCore
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseDatabase

class AddNewObjectiveViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var text : UITextView?
    @IBOutlet var textfield : UITextField!
    
    var transferRow = String()
    

    
    //defining firebase reference var
    var refObjective: DatabaseReference!
    
 
    
    
    
    @IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {

      print(transferRow + "String has been tranfered via tranferRow during save" )
        
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //not perimantent 
        self.text?.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.text?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        
        refObjective = Database.database().reference().child("toolbar");
        
        //transferRow = WeeklyObjectivesEditorViewController().selectedKey
        transferRow = dataPassedMedium   
       // refObjective = Database.database().reference().child("toolbars");
        
        // let bodyFire = refObjective.child("-KwSYtZU_EX1vFFeTI4g").child("body")

                print(transferRow + "String has been tranfered via tranferRow")
      
        let delayInSeconds = 4.0
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delayInSeconds) {


        }
   
        }
    
    
    func addObjective(){
        //generating a new key inside artists node
        //and also getting the generated key
   
        //creating artist with the given values
        let objective = ["id": self.transferRow,
                         "body": self.text?.text! as! String,
                         "title": self.textfield.text! as String
            ] as [String : Any]
        
        //adding the artist inside the generated unique key
        self.self.refObjective.child(self.transferRow).setValue(objective)
        

        
        
    }
    
    
   

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
   
        
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: You basically want to get the `childByAutoId()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To gather the keys to use in a `tableView` you can use a `dictionary` or an `array` - your preference.

```
//This is the key that is desired.
let bodyFire = refObjective.childByAutoId().child("body")
```

In `didSelectRowAt` will be when you select the key:

`let selectedKey = arrayOfIDs[indexPath.row] as? String`

```
//
//  WeeklyObjectivesEditorViewController.swift
//  Studioso
//
//  Created by Charles Porth on 8/29/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Studioso. All rights reserved.
//


import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseDatabase

class WeeklyObjectivesEditorView2ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar1: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var View1: UITabBarItem!

    //defining firebase reference var
    var refToolbars2: DatabaseReference!
    let arrayOfIDs: NSMutableArray = [""]

    // @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewToolbar: UITableView!

    //list to store all the artist
    var toolbarList = [View2ToolbarModel]()

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return toolbarList.count

    }


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        //creating a cell using the custom class
        let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell2

        //the artist object
        let toolbar: View2ToolbarModel

        //getting the artist of selected position
        toolbar = toolbarList[indexPath.row]



        //adding values to labels

        cell1.label.text = toolbar.toolbar1

        //returning cell
        return cell1
    }



    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    //1 == up
//    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar2: UITextField!
//    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar3: UITextField!
//    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar4: UITextField!
//    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar5: UITextField!
//    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar6: UITextField!
//    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar7: UITextField!
//    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar8: UITextField!
//    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar9: UITextField!
//    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar10: UITextField!
//    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar11: UITextField!
//    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar12: UITextField!
//    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar13: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var Remove: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet weak var add: UIBarButtonItem!

    /*
     func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "WeeklyObjectivesViewController" {

            let WeeklyObjectivesViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WeeklyObjectivesViewController") as! WeeklyObjectivesViewController
            */




    //https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2

    @IBAction func buttonToolbar(_ sender: UIButton) {
        addToolbar()

        //reloading the tableview
        self.tableViewToolbar.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
refObjective(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
      if snapshot.value is NSNull{
         //Handle errors
      }
      else{
         arrayOfIDs.removeAllObjects()
         if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
            //dict.allKeys is all the IDs
            for ID in dict.allKeys{
                arrayOfIDs.add(ID as! String) //Will always be a string in Firebase
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
         }
      }
})

        // Add this
        tableViewToolbar.delegate = self
        tableViewToolbar.dataSource = self


        //getting a reference to the node artists
        refToolbars2 = Database.database().reference().child("toolbarsView2");


        //observing the data changes
        refToolbars2.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            //if the reference have some values
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

                //clearing the list
                self.toolbarList.removeAll()

                //iterating through all the values
                for toolbar in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    //getting values
                    let toolbarObject = toolbar.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let toolbarId  = toolbarObject?["id"]
                    let toolbarToolbar1 = toolbarObject?["toolbar1"]


                    //creating artist object with model and fetched values
                    //let toolbar = ToolbarModel(toolbar1: "String?")

                    //creating artist object with model and fetched values
                    let toolbar = View2ToolbarModel(id: toolbarId as! String?, toolbar1: toolbarToolbar1 as! String?)


                    //appending it to list
                    self.toolbarList.append(toolbar)
                } 

                //reloading the tableview
                self.tableViewToolbar.reloadData()
            }
        })
       // scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height + 83)




    }

    func addToolbar(){
        //generating a new key inside artists node
        //and also getting the generated key
        let key = refToolbars2.childByAutoId().key

        //creating artist with the given values
        let toolbar = ["id":key,
                       "toolbar1": toolbar1.text! as String,
                       //                      "toolbar2": toolbar2.text! as String,
            //                      "toolbar3": toolbar3.text! as String,
            //                      "toolbar4": toolbar4.text! as String,
            //                      "toolbar5": toolbar5.text! as String,
            //                      "toolbar6": toolbar6.text! as String,
            //                      "toolbar7": toolbar7.text! as String,
            //                      "toolbar8": toolbar8.text! as String,
            //                      "toolbar9": toolbar9.text! as String,
            //                      "toolbar10": toolbar10.text! as String,
            //                      "toolbar11": toolbar11.text! as String,
            //                      "toolbar12": toolbar12.text! as String,
        ]

        //adding the artist inside the generated unique key
        refToolbars2.child(key).setValue(toolbar)
        //        refToolbars.child(key).setValue(toolbar1)
        //        refToolbars.child(key).setValue(toolbar2)
        //        refToolbars.child(key).setValue(toolbar3)
        //        refToolbars.child(key).setValue(toolbar4)
        //        refToolbars.child(key).setValue(toolbar5)
        //        refToolbars.child(key).setValue(toolbar6)
        //        refToolbars.child(key).setValue(toolbar7)
        //        refToolbars.child(key).setValue(toolbar8)
        //        refToolbars.child(key).setValue(toolbar9)
        //        refToolbars.child(key).setValue(toolbar10)
        //        refToolbars.child(key).setValue(toolbar11)
        //        refToolbars.child(key).setValue(toolbar12)
        //


        //displaying message
        //  labelMessage.text = "toolbar"

        //https://www.simplifiedios.net/firebase-realtime-database-tutorial/


    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }








//    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: AnyObject!) {
//        let segueName: String = segue.identifier!;
//        if (segueName == "addButton") {
//            let weeklyObjectivesViewController = segue.destination as! WeeklyObjectivesViewController;
//
////            weeklyObjectivesViewController.stringPassed1 = toolbar1.text
//
//        }
//    }
//
}

//
//  AddNewObjective.swift
//  Studioso
//
//  Created by Charles Porth on 9/21/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Studioso. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import QuartzCore
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseDatabase

class AddNewObjectiveViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var text : UITextView?
    @IBOutlet var textfield : UITextField!
    var selectedKey = ""
    var transferRow: String = ""
    //defining firebase reference var
    var refObjective: DatabaseReference!

    //var textString: String!
    //var textfieldString: String!


    //https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html


    @IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {

//        self.updateToolbar(id: <#String#>)
     addObjective()
//        bodyReturn.body = self.text?.text
//       bodyReturn.title = self.textfield.text

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //not perimantent 
        self.text?.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.text?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        print(selectedKey)
        refObjective = Database.database().reference().child("toolbar");

//        toolbar.selectedKey = self.transferRow!

       // refObjective = Database.database().reference().child("toolbars");

        // let bodyFire = refObjective.child("-KwSYtZU_EX1vFFeTI4g").child("body")

                print(self.transferRow)

//        let bodyFire = self.refObjective.child(transferRow).child("body")
//                bodyFire.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
//                    let bodyOnFire  = snapshot.value as? String
//                    self.text?.text = bodyOnFire
//
////
//                let titleFire = self.refObjective.child("id").child("title")
//                titleFire.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
//                    let titleOnFire = snapshot.value as? String
//                    self.textfield.text = titleOnFire
//

       // })
        //This is the key that is desired.


//       self.transferRow = WeeklyObjectivesEditorViewController.toolbarList[indexPath.row]
//


        }


    func addObjective(){
        //generating a new key inside artists node
        //and also getting the generated key
        //let key = refObjective.childByAutoId().key

       //   let key = refObjective.child("-KwSYtZU_EX1vFFeTI4g").key

        //creating artist with the given values
        let objective = ["id": self.transferRow,
                         "body": text?.text! as! String,
                         "title": textfield.text! as String
            ] as [String : Any]

        //adding the artist inside the generated unique key
        refObjective.child(self.transferRow).setValue(objective)

        //displaying message



    }



//    func updateToolbar(id:String){
//        //creating artist with the new given values
//        let objective = ["id":id,
//                      "body": text?.text! as! String,
//                      "title": textfield.text! as! String,
//        ]
//
//        //updating the artist using the key of the artist
//        refObjective.child(id).setValue(objective)
//
//    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }






}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157091/discussion-on-answer-by-torewin-how-would-i-pull-the-key-from-firebase-of-an-alr).